# MySQL query missing IDs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables, I want to query which people were absent (missing in the event i.e when a `idu` is missing in the attendance table for a certain event) from an event and how many times they were absent within a certain date range. For example if an event happens 5 times and a user goes to one of them, I want to be shown that a user missed Four events.
 I also would like to set the least amount of times an individual can be absent to be included in the absentee list to be 3. Therefore the query will show me users who have missed events more than 3 time. My tables are as show below

**Users Table**

```
idu     fname   lname
1       John    Doe
2       Jane    Doe
3       Mary    Jane
4       John    Rancho
```

**Events Table**

```
id_event    event_name
1           Conference
2           Fellowship
3           Orientation
```

**Events attendance table**

```
id_attendance   id_event    idu event_date
1               1           1   2012-02-01 08:00:00
2               1           2   2012-02-01 08:00:00
3               2           1   2012-06-07 08:00:00
4               2           3   2012-06-07 08:00:00
5               3           1   2013-07-12 08:00:00
6               3           2   2013-07-12 08:00:00
7               1           1   2014-05-31 08:00:00
8               1           3   2014-05-31 08:00:00
9               2           1   2015-02-08 08:00:00
```

I would like the results to be shown as below whereby the first column is the `idu`
Therefore the results will look like so

```
IDU  Name      Times Absent
2   Jane Doe    3
3   Mary Jane   4
```

My query is shown below. I'm stuck.

```
SELECT idu 
FROM users 
WHERE idu NOT IN (
         SELECT idu 
         FROM events 
         LEFT JOIN attendance 
         ON event_id=id_event
         WHERE event_date>='2011-04-08 00:00:00' 
         AND event_date<='2019-04-08 00:00:00'
         AND id_event IN(11,10) AND idu IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Please explain what "absent" means in terms of your data (it is clearly not a field in any of the tables).  Also, how to you get the values of 3 and 4 for those two users, given the data in the question?

Comment: You have a problem here in your schema in that you have multiple event data for a single event id.  This make is unclear as to what it means to "miss" an event. If an event happens 5 times and a user goes to one of them.  How many events did they miss?  Did they miss 4 events?  Did they not "miss" this event at all since they went at least once?

Comment: @Mike, I want to query when an idu is missing in the attendance table for a certain event. For example if an event happens 5 times and a user goes to one of them, I want to be shown that a user missed Four events.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have rephrased the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    ut.idu as IDU,
    ut.fname || ut.lname as Name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events_table) - SUM(CASE WHEN at.idu is null then 0 else 1 end) as TimesAbsent
FROM attendance_table at
RIGHT JOIN user_table ut
ON at.idu = ut.idu
GROUP BY ut.idu, ut.fname, ut.lname
```

Comment: I need to know the times a user did not show up or a user who never showed up at all.

Comment: I fixed, now with the right join is counting the user who never showed up

Comment: Thanks for the help. Works, now I have to know how to deal with the negatives

Answer (score 0):

I think, you want to get number of users that, they have more than or equal to four absents.

Please use the below query.

```
select
*
from
(select
u.idu as IDU,concat(u.fname,' ', u.lname) as Name,
(CASE
WHEN a.idu IS NULL THEN (SELECT  count(distinct id_event,event_date) FROM attendance)
ELSE ((SELECT  count(distinct id_event,event_date) FROM attendance) - count(*))
END) as Number_of_Absent
from users u
left join attendance a on (a.idu=u.idu)
group by concat(u.fname,' ', u.lname) order by Number_of_Absent) a where Number_of_Absent >=4 ;
```

You can see the query result please click..  [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d74c/3)

If you want to see all users absent then you can try the below query.

```
select
u.idu as IDU, concat(u.fname,' ', u.lname) as Name,
(CASE
WHEN a.idu IS NULL THEN (SELECT  count(distinct id_event,event_date) FROM attendance)
ELSE ((SELECT  count(distinct id_event,event_date) FROM attendance) - count(*))
END) as Number_of_Absent
from users u
left join attendance a on (a.idu=u.idu)
group by concat(u.fname,' ', u.lname) order by Number_of_Absent
```

You can see the query result please click..  [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d74c/5)

According to the above tables data following users absent list

[image]